# Circuits Gate design-NOR

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

[image]

hello,I am trying to do that electronic diagram in the tinkecad. This diagram is a NOR Gate circuit.
What I did is this [image]

Can you tell me what I have done  wrong ? The second image is what I did,but I don't know what is wrong with it..[image]

Comment: What did you expect to see, and what did you actually see? Please add that information to your question.

Comment: It must work the led without any damage

Comment: no it is correctly

Comment: I don't know TinkerCAD, but it looks like there is something about the connection from the 74HC32 pin 7 to Ground that TinkerCad doesn't like.  The connection between the resistor and LED is suspect - looks like it connects to pin 6 of the 74HC04.

Answer (score 0):

Pin 8 of the HC32 is not connected to ground.

Also, in real breadboards, between pin 30 and pin 31 you need to put one jumper wire for VCC and one for GND.

Comment: I have done it .But I forgot to screenshot and upload that image.It still not working with that

Comment: I've never seen a breadboard that required jumpers there, though I know they exist.

Comment: @Yun.kon: Please upload a corrected photo - we can only comment on what you show us.

Answer (score 0):

You did not connect U1 pin7 to ground.

Comment: I have done it .But I forgot to screenshot and upload that image.It still not working with that - i have image

Comment: @Yun.kon possible something wrong with modeled breadboard. Try jumpers straight from power supply to pins 7 and 14 of U2.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the LED and resistor connected to pin6 of the 74LS04. Pin 6 is an output.